# Como solucionar DIRTY_WORKTREE

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Estou tentando dar um merge no `git`usando o eclipse, porém ele me apresenta um erro:

> DIRTY_WORKTREE "nome do arquivo".

Já tentei reverter o `commit` e `resetar`, porém não funciona nenhuma das duas opções.

Comment: Se você utilizar na linha de comando `git status` qual a é a saída exibida?

Comment: Tenta deletar os arquivos afetados e da pull de novo.

Answer (score 2):

Entra num shell até seu repository.

Digite `git status` para ver os arquivos modificados desde o ultimo commit.
Digite `git diff` para ver as diferencias se quizer.

2 opções:

Faz um commit para "limpar" o repository:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Messagem das modificações"
```

OU

Apage as modificações:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

Depois, o repository sera limpado e o merge sera possivel.

PS: Para cancelar um merge ainda não commitado:

```
git reset --merge
```